# How can I build an older GCC version (8.5.0) on a newer Linux distribution (Devuan Excalibur/Debian Trixie)?

Tags: compiling, gcc, compatibility, devuan

If I download and try to build GCC 8.x on a newer machine, e.g. Devuan Excalibur GNU/Linux (i.e. Debian Trixie without systemd) -  this fails, with the error going something like this:

```
libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found
```

If I manually copy my system's `libstdc++6.so` over the file missing the relevant [?] - and repeat the process a few times - I get to a different error:

```
make[7]: Entering directory '/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/32/libitm'
In file included from /usr/include/linux/fs.h:19,
                 from ../../.././libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:68:
/usr/include/linux/mount.h:96:6: error: multiple definition of ‘enum fsconfig_command’
 enum fsconfig_command {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../.././libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:55:
/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/include-fixed/sys/mount.h:249:6: note: previous definition here
 enum fsconfig_command
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/linux/fs.h:19,
                 from ../../.././libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:68:
/usr/include/linux/mount.h:130:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct mount_attr’
 struct mount_attr {
        ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../.././libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_platform_limits_posix.cc:55:
/usr/local/src/gcc-8.5.0/host-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc/include-fixed/sys/mount.h:219:8: note: previous definition of ‘struct mount_attr’
 struct mount_attr
        ^~~~~~~~~~
```

which is weird, but perhaps my fault for trying to force the library version. Anyway - how can I GCC 8.5.0 to actually build on my machine?

Note:

- The configuration is: `./configure --disable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++`.
- Any additional information will be provided per request.

Comment: There might be a difference between Devuan and Debian here — the build works fine for me on Debian 13.

Comment: @StephenKitt : Fair comment, but it might also be something on my specific system (e.g. since I dist-upgraded from chimaera to daedalus to excalibur or for another reason) rather than a Debian-vs-Devuan difference.

Comment: Yes, it could be (I can’t think of a difference between Devuan and Debian which would produce this result). The same procedure works fine for me on Debian 11 and 12 too. You could try building without `libstdc++` (`--disable-libstdcxx`).

Comment: @StephenKitt: I'll try it, just to see what kind of errors I'm getting; but I do _want_ libstdcxx .

Comment: Right, but do you need the GCC 8 version, or is the current version in your distro OK?

Comment: @StephenKitt: I need GCC 8.x to use with CUDA 10.x, which doesn't support newer GCC versions; and I need to use CUDA 10.x since I'm the author of a library which involves CUDA, and I want it to support CUDA 10.x. Also - the trial worked: The build completed successfully when I didn't build libstdcxx.

Comment: Yes, it was clear you needed GCC 8, I was just wondering about `libstdc++`.

Comment: @StephenKitt: My test programs use libstdc++ ; my library itself doesn't require it for linking.

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767757/im-using-distribution-x-that-was-shipped-with-compiler-y-but-i-need-compiler) for an sane approach to solving your issue.

Comment: @eyoung100: It doesn't resolve my issue, I don't want a containerized or virtualized environment, I want the one I have now. Will post an answer soon.

Comment: Then consider at least using the tools from `build-essential` in your repo and [the package manager agnostic documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) in a changeroot, so you minimize risk to your system.

Comment: @eyoung100: I could, but if you'll look at my answer, you'll see it's much simpler than that, with no risk of danger to the system.

Answer (score 0):

The solution involves several steps:

- Install apt packages for the static 64-bit and 32-bit version of the GCC standard C++ library: `libstdc++-dev` and `lib32stdc++-dev`
- Configure the GCC repository so as not to build the sanitizer library: Add `--disable-libsanitizer` argument for the `configure` command.

That should do the trick. Note that, over time and with newer versions of Debian, more things might break than you can hope to fix or get around.

Relevant GCC "bug" pages:

- [87858: Building old multilib bootstrap GCC: stage1 32-bit libstdc++ fails to build after building 64-bit libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87858)
- [113181: When compiling sanitizer_printf.cc, getting error: multiple definition of ‘enum fsconfig_command’](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=113181)